# Cannot figure out the syntax error I'm getting on line 1- python

Tags: python

```
first_name = input("What is your first name?:")
print("Hello, {}").format(first_name)


if first_name == "Craig":
    print(first_name, "is learning Python")
elif first_name == "Maximiliane":
    print(first_name, "is learing with fellow students.   Me too")
else:
    # This is just in case we have a younger user who can't yet read
    age = int(input("How old are you?  "))
    if age <= 6:
        print("Wow you're {}: if you're confident with your reading already.....".format(age)
    print("You should totally learn Python, {}!".format(first_name))
print("Have a great day {}!".format(first_name))
```

Comment: Show us the full error output.

Comment: Your first line seems okay. Your second line has parentheses which don't make sense

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: `.format()` is an attribute of `'str'` object, not `NoneType` object.

Comment: The question is liable to downvotes as it may not be useful and may only be applicable to solvle this current problem. Nevertheless, the syntax error is just due to unbalanced bracketing on two lines.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this statement:

```
print("Hello, {}").format(first_name)
```

The line should utilize the `format()` method this way

```
print("Hello, {}".format(first_name))
```

Also, there you have forgotten a bracket with this line!

```
print("Wow you're {}: if you're confident with your reading already.....".format(age)) #I have added the last bracket right now
```

To help you never encounter this syntax problem again, `format()` method takes any number of parameters, but they are divided into 2 specific types:

**Positional parameters** - list of parameters that can be accessed with index of parameter inside curly braces {index}

**Keyword parameters** - list of parameters of type key=value, that can be accessed with key of parameter inside curly braces {key}

This will solve your problem! Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I missed that one! Thanks! @Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩᛗ

Answer (score 1):

The `.format` function has to be called within the print function, like this:

```
print( "Hello, {}".format(first_name) )
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. There are mismatched parenthesis (not brackets), which also represent syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

print("Wow you're {}: if you're confident with your reading already.....".format(age)

Missing “)” above code